# JAX-RS upload file without Jersey

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I would like to know how to create a REST webservice that posts multipart request to upload the file without using third party libraries like Jersey or Spring.

Thanks.

Comment: try [this example](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-file-upload-example-with-servlet-30-api)

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/uploadfile")
void uploadFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Multipart(value = "file", type = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)Attachment file);
```

Comment: which annotation is @Multipart?

Comment: aerm, which package exactly do I use for Attachment?

Comment: This is not a good answer as it relies on another proprietary solution, or in other words, this is not a pure JAX-RS solution.