# How to upload file in Restful Service - JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, io, jax-rs, wso2-as

I want to implement a Restful service to upload a file. Following is what I have done so far. I can't get the file.

Service Interface

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/upload-ifc")
public boolean uploadIfcFile(Attachment file)
```

The implementation as follows

```
public boolean uploadIfcFile(Attachment attachment) throws IOException {

        LOG.info("Uploding the ifcFile.....");

        if (attachment != null) {
            LOG.info("GOT___ATTACHMENT");
        } else {
            LOG.info("ATTACHMENT_NULL");
        }

        Object o = attachment.getObject();
        if (o != null) {
            LOG.info("GOT_OBJECT");
        } else {
            LOG.info("OBJECT_NULL");
        }

        File ifcFile = (File) o;

        LOG.info("___________: " + ifcFile.getName());

        return controller.uploadIfcFile(ifcFile);
    }
```

**OUTPUT is**

```
Uploding the ifcFile.....
GOT___ATTACHMENT
OBJECT_NULL
```

I don't know how to get access the file here. I searched a lot but couldn't get a good resource. I am deploying this in [wso2 application server](http://wso2.com/products/application-server/) and Jax rs implementation is Axis2 CXF.

Comment: What is the implementation of `Attachment`?

Comment: Are you using Jersey?

Comment: @Smutje it is org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment

Comment: @sgpalit No, I'm using wso2 products and it uses axis2 CXF.

Comment: Use attachment.getValue()

Comment: @kingAm `getValue()` method is not available in `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment`

Comment: Have you seen this related question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556982/jax-rs-upload-file-without-jersey

Did you solve?